# Why do my analytics report that index.php appears in URLs despite friendly URL rewrite rules?

Tags: seo, google-analytics, redirects, mod-rewrite

On a website i use mod_rewrite and PHP to create clean URL's.

My `.htaccess` (summary) will look like that shown below:

```
RewriteEngine On

#oude pagina's
RewriteRule     ^nl/links/(.*)/index.php$    /nl/links/$1/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2}/[a-zA-Z0-9/\-_]+)/$ /index.php?navid=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

When using a browser the above seems to work well

`/nl/links/eropuit/vakantie/rondreizen/` shows the right content, and `/nl/links/eropuit/vakantie/rondreizen/index.php` redirects to `/nl/links/eropuit/vakantie/rondreizen/`

But when i take a look at the most visited pages at Google Adsense (Analytics), it tells me a index.php is found for every URL:

[image]

Now I wonder why that `index.php` is found / detected and whether I should worry about it.

Comment: Is that Google AdSense or Google Analytics?   Google AdSense has reporting about which pages on your site it shows advertisements on, so that report could be from it, but it looks more like a report from Google Analytics to me.

Comment: You are presumably linking only to the "clean" canonical URL throughout your site and sitemap etc.?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller the image is from Google Adsense which got a graph which is called "Analytics". But also Google Analytics tells me the index.php is used.

Comment: @MrWhite yes indeed, the clean URL is use for both internal linking and the sitemap. I do never link the index.php, so why do Google find it? Also in the search results on Google the url with index.php is not found.

Comment: Have these URLs with `index.php` _ever_ existed (as public facing URLs)? Do these URLs appear in client-side JS? Are there any inbound links to these URLs? If these URLs have _never_ been referenced publicly (and they have always successfully redirected) then Google shouldn't "find it". Is there a physical `index.php` file on your system in these places? If the redirect wasn't in place would that URL return the same response?

Comment: @MrWhite as far as i do understand i should anser all your questions negative, that's why i do not understand what happens. After detecting that an index.php was found, the `RewriteRule     ^nl/links/(.*)/index.php$    /nl/links/$1/ [L,R=301]` had been added.
About your last question. I do not understand what you mean. Which redirect?

Comment: If the redirect (that removes the trailing `index.php`) was not in place, would a URL of the form `/nl/links/eropuit/vakantie/rondreizen/index.php` return the same resource as `/nl/links/eropuit/vakantie/rondreizen/`? Would it return a 4xx status code? (Although I guess it wouldn't return the same resource going off the few directives you posted? But this would make it a bigger mystery.)

Comment: @MrWhite In the current situation:
`/links/eropuit/vakantie/rondreizen/index.php` gives -> 301 -> 301 -> 200
and `/links/eropuit/vakantie/rondreizen/` gives -> 302 -> 200
Both show the same page.
When i do remove `RewriteRule     ^nl/links/(.*)/index.php$    /nl/links/$1/ [L,R=301]`
`/links/eropuit/vakantie/rondreizen/` gives -> 302 -> 200 and show the same pages as above
`/links/eropuit/vakantie/rondreizen/index.php` now gives -> 301 -> 301 (its seems it follow to `/links/eropuit/vakantie/rondreizen/index.php/`?) -> 302 ->200 and it shows the homepage (`/`)

Comment: It is possible for GA to add the index.php. If you look at Admin > View Settings is anything filled into Default Page? (right underneath time zone)

Comment: Are you using the standard GA tracking code to record pageviews? Not some custom script that might be looking at the filename instead of the URI?

Comment: @Reve it can be simple. That's the solution. Please add your  answer below, so i can approve it. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide me a link to your WEB to check it? It's interesting case. Thanks.

Comment: _Aside:_ Those redirects don't _look_ correct?! Why is your "canonical" URL `/links/eropuit/vakantie/rondreizen/` redirecting (302)? What is it redirecting too? Your "canonical URL" should not be redirecting at all. Why does the same URL with `index.php` seemingly result in 2 x 301 redirects? (Why not a 301, followed by a 302 - given the seemingly "erroneous" 302 redirect you are seeing for the above "canonical" URL?)

Comment: @Taha. I'm not sure if i'm allowed to share the link in the comments. Please send my a e-mail

Comment: @MrWhite. Thanks. Yes something seems wrong. I will look at it and create a new question maybe.

Comment: @mrWhite thank. https://www.linkotheek.nl/, also think the redirection is fixed (caused by a switch between https and http)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Analytics provides a way to add a filename to any page path ending with a slash, in order to standardize data for pages that might be accessible with or without the filename. Look in Admin > View Settings for the Default Page field, right underneath time zone. An `index.php` in that field is your reason!